# preferred include header for std::size_t

Tags: c++

`std::size_t` is defined in any of:
`<cstddef>` `<cstdio>` `<cstdlib>` `<cstring>` `<ctime>` `<cwchar>`

Which is considered 'kosher' for getting just `std::size_t`?

Comment: I'd use `<cstddef>`, as it represents "standard definitions" and seems to be quite minimal: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef

Comment: I'd consider including `ctime` just for size_t to be a bit boneheaded, don't you think?

Comment: I just found a note in the standard §5.3.3.6 that reads *[ Note: std::size_t is defined in the standard header <cstddef> (18.2). — end note ]*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is part of the C library I think the C standard specified header is the right one: `stddef.h`, i.e. `cstddef`.

From C11:

> 7.19 Common definitions
>
> The header  defines the following macros and declares the following types. Some are also defined in other headers, as noted in their respective subclauses.
>
> [...]
>   `size_t` which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the
>   sizeof operator;

This is after all a C++ question so I think a quote from the C++ standard is more appropriate:

> 18.2 Types
>
> Table 30 describes the header `<cstddef>`.
>
> Types:  `ptrdiff_t` **`size_t`**  `max_align_t` `nullptr_t`